# How to style PHP generated tags?

Tags: php, css

Which is better inline styling or linking a redundant stylesheet? What i mean by redundant is, when you want to generate different outputs for different results, that can mean many different styling for a specific tag in the css markup.

Answer (score 2):

Separating your styles into stylesheets is almost always preferable to inline `style` attributes.  You can assign classes to tags in your PHP output, which are then styled in your CSS stylesheets.  It is trivially easy to restyle all elements of a tag type or class by modifying the stylesheet then.

Separate stylesheets are also crucially important if you wish to use the same HTML markup to produce different visual styles for different screen/device types such as mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

A tag is a tag is a tag. It is on the client. The client has no idea that the tag was created by PHP, .NET or someone typing on a keyboard on the moon.

Use a stylesheet and class names. It's better to use an external stylesheet so the browser can cache it on subsequent page loads.

```
<div class="...."></div>

div.happy {
    color:#00ff00
}

div.sad {
    color:#ff0000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

allways use linked styles, its usefull when you want to make templates and because it will go to cache your page will open faster , aslo you will score more on search bots (eg. googlebot) and you page can be higher ranked

for linking use something like

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://yourURL/css/styles.css" media="screen" />
```

php can output for you html and you can apply css to it

```
echo '<div id="something"><a class="link"><span><h1>text</h1></span></a></div>";
```

and you can use

```
#something {
 font-size:10px;
}
.link{
color:#333
}
a.class{
font-weight:bold;
}
a span {
 text-align:right;
}
h1{
 color:red
}
```